# PHP, IIS, Oracle (OCI) not working

Tags: php, oracle, iis, windows-server, oracle-call-interface

We are migrating from a Windows SBS 2011 to Windows Server 2012 R2.

We have an internal website that connects to our Oracle database using PHP.

I am trying to migrate this to the new server and so far I have:

1. Installed IIS Server Role
2. Installed PHP
3. Downloaded Oracle Instant Client to C:\instantclient
4. Added C:\instantclient to PATH System Variable
5. Added php_oci8.dll to php.ini and checked that PHP is actually using this php.ini
6. Restarted server

I am still getting error messages like oci_ commands not being recognised etc.

I'm lost. I've searched online and the instructions match what I have done from memory.

I haven't found a single thing online that I haven't done.

Comment: So `phpinfo()` lists oci8?

Comment: Couple of possibilities then. One is that your DLL was not compiled for the version of PHP you have installed. The other is that the path is still wrong.

Comment: I think it's more a Windows thing since instant client is the same. Is it just PATH that I need to set?

Comment: It probably is (even some WAMP stacks have issues like this). But PATH should work http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx

Comment: I definitely have it set. Is it just PATH or are there others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the version of InstantClient you have installed you might need to include the `bin` folder in the path, like so:

```
C:\instantclient\bin
```

To check if the DLL files are available in the path enter `where oci*.dll` in a command prompt.  It should return a list of matching files.

Also, remember that just because your account can see the DLL files doesn't mean IIS/PHP can.  That runs under a different account that might not have permission to access the files.  Check your IIS error log and PHP `php_errors.log` file for any specific error messages.

---

***Edit***

After a rather lengthy [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/66490), the problem was resolved by:

- Updating the InstantClient from 10.1.0.5 to 10.2.0.5 (as mentioned in the [module requirements](http://php.net/manual/en/oci8.requirements.php): *On Windows, the php_oci8 DLL needs Oracle client libraries from version 10gR2 or greater.*)
- Adding a copy of `msvcr71.dll` to the InstantClient folder.
- Downloading and manually configuring PHP from [php.net](http://windows.php.net/download) instead of using [PHP Manager for IIS](https://phpmanager.codeplex.com/).
- Ensuring the `Path` environment variable correctly pointed to the InstantClient and PHP folders.

Comment: There is no `\bin` inside my Instant Client. The only PHP errors are that commands such as `oci_connect` are not found.

Comment: Usual behaviour when OCI cannot be loaded is for PHP to log an error like `PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_oci8_11g.dll' - The specified module could not be found.`.  This would definitively tell you there is a startup error.  Have you confirmed the `oci*.dll` files are available in the path, and that the IIS user can access them?

Comment: Yes, `C:\instantclient` (where the `oci*.dll` files are) is in `PATH` and `Everyone` has full access as a test.

Comment: Does 'bitness' of everything match? PHP (>=5.5) and InstantClient are available in 32 or 64bit.  They need to be the same for PHP to be able to use the `oci*.dll` files.

Comment: Yes, I chose 32 bit when downloading the Instant Client and PHP is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3` (even though PHP Manager IIS seems to be in `C:\Program Files\`).

Comment: What's the version of InstantClient?  In older versions (<11) OCI wouldn't work if there was a parenthesis in the path, such as with `Program Files (x86)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66490/discussion-between-timclutton-and-user4166144).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

extension=php_oci8_12c.dll 
(instead of php_oci8.dll) - that is what I am using and you probably downloaded the same instant client as I did.